# diff file in worktree with file in the remote tracking branch

Tags: git, git-worktree

I have this command:

```
git diff -w remotes/origin/dev:"$file" HEAD:"$file"
```

I am wondering how to diff it with the worktree instead of HEAD, like this:

```
git diff -w remotes/origin/dev:"$file" WORKTREE:"$file"
```

maybe the way to do it is just like this?

```
git diff -w remotes/origin/dev:"$file" "$file"
```

anyone know?

Comment: Yes, it's that last form. There is nothing special about remote-tracking names *here:* as with any other name, it just identifies a commit. The only thing special about remote-tracking names like `origin/dev` is that your `git fetch` will update them when you `git fetch` from `origin`, based on what your Git gets from `origin`'s Git.

Comment: and I guess if you wanted to do cached/staged you would use `--cached` or `--staged`?

Comment: Yes. Note that `--cached` and `--staged` are synonyms. I think `staged` is superior word-wise, but tend to use `cached` even with `git diff` because `git rm` does not have the `--staged` spelling.

Comment: yeah unfortunate aliasing there, but mistakes happen lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do this trick:

```
git diff -w remotes/origin/dev:"$file" "$file"
```